# Data recovery is it possible: Ubuntu Chrome OS Acer 710

Tags: google-chrome, acer, chromebook

I know it is tricky and only a bunch of people out there with Acer chrome book c710 running Ubuntu. Following is the situation.

I installed Ubuntu LTS 12.04 on Acer Chromebook. Fantastic!. I stored lot of images family pictures and videos and documents. 
Accidentally some one at my home pushed the space bar while booting BAD, all rest to chrome OS, whole process of installing Ubuntu was repeated. This indicates that the drive was partitioned/repartitioned and reset.

Is there a way to recover the data (the pictures videos and documents).

so far, I have not done anything other than reinstalling the ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I called some data recovery companies including staples. They said as long as it is working drive, data is a data, image once created can be recovered but costs huge amount of money

Can anyone make suggestions to recover the pictures and videos

Thanks